# Generating key pair from passphrase in libsodium

Tags: public-key, libsodium

I would like to generate a public/private key pair deterministically  from a passphrase with `libsodium`.
Whenever/wherever the user types his passphrase, s/he will get back the same key pair.

My approach is to acquire the passphrase somehow (e.g., `fgets`), hash it with `crypto_generichash`, and then use the hash as a seed to `crypto_sign_seed_keypair`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sodium.h>

int main (void) {
    char passphrase[1024];
    printf("ENTER PASSPHRASE: ");
    {
        char* ret = fgets(passphrase, sizeof(passphrase), stdin);
        assert(ret != NULL);
        assert(passphrase[strlen(passphrase)-1] == '\n');
        passphrase[strlen(passphrase)-1] = '\0';
    }

    unsigned char hash[crypto_generichash_BYTES];
    {
        int ret = crypto_generichash(hash, crypto_generichash_BYTES,
                                     (unsigned char*)passphrase, strlen(passphrase),
                                     NULL, 0);
        assert(ret == 0);
    }

    unsigned char pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    unsigned char sk[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    {
        assert(crypto_generichash_BYTES == crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES);
        int ret = crypto_sign_seed_keypair(pk, sk, hash);
        assert(ret == 0);
    }
    printf("PUBLIC KEY:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", pk[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("PRIVATE KEY:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", sk[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming the passphrase is strong, is this scheme safe and practical?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but even a "strong" passphrase has a pretty low entropy. Therefore, instead of a generic hash function, you may want to use a [password hashing function](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/password_hashing/the_argon2i_function.html).

Comment: In my case, since the user would not be able to find out the salt, should I just use a fixed value? (The hash/salt is not stored anywhere.) Is it still much better than a generic hash?

Comment: A fixed salt is fine. You can set it to something unique to your application.